# Finding average GPA C++

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

This is probably a stupid question.
I am fairly new to programming.

I am trying to find the average GPA of each student. The first for loop I have will list the student name then go into a nested for loop which has you enter a letter grade 10 times. Once they enter the letter grade, depending on what letter it is the if/else statements turn it into a number which then adds it to the array arr[100]. After you enter 10 grades for one students it displays the average gpa.

The issue I am having is that once you enter the 10 grades for the first student it find the GPA just fine. However, once you get to the second student it is adding the first students average GPA to the 2nd students and so on.

How should I go about fixing this?

Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 


int main() {
    float sum = 0.0, average;
    int y;
    string grades;
    float arr[100];
    string totalStudents[10] = {"Malcolm 'Mal' Reynolds", "Inara Serra", "River Tam", "Kaylee Frye", "Zoe Washburne", "Jayne Cobb", "Hoban 'Wash' Washburne", "Simon Tam", "Shepherd Derrial Book", "Mr. Universe"};

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(totalStudents); i++) {
        cout<<"Please enter grades for " << totalStudents[i] <<endl;
        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
            cout << "Enter letter grade " << y + 1 << ":"<< endl;
            cin >> grades;

            if (grades == "A" || grades == "a") {

                arr[y] += 4;

            }else if (grades == "B" || grades == "b") {
                arr[y] += 3;
            }else if (grades == "C" || grades == "c") {
                arr[y] += 2;
            
            }else if (grades == "D" || grades == "d") {
                arr[y] += 1;


            }else if (grades == "F" || grades == "f") {
                arr[y] += 0;
            

        }

            sum += arr[y];

        
         }

            average = sum/10;
            cout << totalStudents[i] << " GPA is: " << fixed << setprecision(1) << average << endl;



    }



    }
```

Comment: Well, your code initializes `sum` to 0 right at the beginning. After the first GPA is calculated, based on the accumulated sum, the shown code then proceeds and starts adding the 2nd student's grades into sum, which results in the results you've correctly analyzed. So, shouldn't it be obvious to you that your program needs to reset `sum` to 0, when beginning to process ***every*** student's grades, rather than the beginning of the entire program?

Comment: Another error is `sizeof(totalStudents)`. You clearly think that this will be 10 since that's the number of strings in the array. But sizeof gives you the number of **bytes** in an array, not the number of elements. The best way to get the sizeof an array is to use the `std::size` function, i.e. `std::size(totalStudents)` ,another way is to divide the size of the array in bytes by the size of one element, i.e. `sizeof(totalStudents)/sizeof(totalStudents[0])`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik These things are often not obvious to beginners, because beginners still have to adjust to the precision required when 'talking' to the compiler. However illogical it is they still have a casual 'it will know what I mean' attitude, and expect the compiler to do what they want it to do rather than to do exactly what they say.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes so I did this and it is still adding to it. I think the issue is that I need to clear out the array arr[100]. Not quite sure how to do this though.

Comment: @cabbott Write a loop and set each element to zero.

Comment: @cabbott Mind you it's not obvious to me why you need the array since all you are doing is adding up numbers. Why not add to `sum` directly, instead of adding to the array and then adding that to `sum`.

Answer (score 0):

> I've just modified some of your code,
> You don't need an extra array to solve this
>
> > NOTE : If you want to store GPA's then you can use an array but if not the given code will works fine for you

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 


int main() {
    float sum = 0.0, average;
    int y;
    string grades;

    string totalStudents[10] = {"Malcolm 'Mal' Reynolds", "Inara Serra", "River Tam", "Kaylee Frye", "Zoe Washburne", "Jayne Cobb", "Hoban 'Wash' Washburne", "Simon Tam", "Shepherd Derrial Book", "Mr. Universe"};

    for (int i=0; i < sizeof(totalStudents); i++) {

        sum=0.0;

        cout<<"Please enter grades for " << totalStudents[i] <<endl;

        for (int y = 0; y < 10; y++) {

            cout << "Enter letter grade " << y + 1 << ": "<< endl;
            cin >> grades;

            if (grades == "A" || grades == "a") {
                sum += 4.0;

            }else if (grades == "B" || grades == "b") {
                sum += 3.0;

            }else if (grades == "C" || grades == "c") {
                sum += 2.0;
            
            }else if (grades == "D" || grades == "d") {
                sum += 1.0;

            }else if (grades == "F" || grades == "f") {
                sum += 0.0;
            
            }

         }

            average = sum/10.0;
            cout << totalStudents[i] << " GPA is : " << fixed << setprecision(1) << average << endl<<endl;

    }

 }
```